# N+1 queries for categories

Tags: channel-entries, categories

I am working on a feature where I need to get every entries category and that categories parent category. This is leading to a lot of DB queries. Is there a way to get the category of an entry and that categories parent. Ultimately I am after just the category url title.

```
Psuedo code
    {exp:channel:entries}
      {entry:category:url_title}
      {entry:category:parent_category:url_title
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would using the [channel categories tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html) allow you to get the results you need?

```
{exp:channel:categories 
    channel="your_channel"
    show_empty="no"
    parent_only="yes"
}
    {category_url_title}<br>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```